# Error consumiendo Web Service

Tags: vb.net, .net, webservice, aeat-sii

Para el mes de Julio se va a implantar un nuevo servicio de la Agencia Tributaria española (AEAT) por el que mediante Web Service se va a enviar información de la facturación de la empresa. El sistema es el SII (Suministro Inmediato de Información).

La agencia ha publicado los WSDL de prueba en [la siguiente liga](http://www.agenciatributaria.es/AEAT.internet/Inicio/Ayuda/Modelos__Procedimientos_y_Servicios/Ayuda_P_G417____IVA__Llevanza_de_libros_registro__SII_/Ayuda_tecnica/Informacion_tecnica_SII/WSDL_de_los_servicios_web/WSDL_de_los_servicios_web.shtml) Tengo que desarrollar el proyecto en VB .Net o C#. Este servicio sólo se podrá usar teniendo instalado un certificado correcto.

Inicialmente he creado un proyecto y he agregado un referencia a uno de los WSDL añadiendo una nueva *Service Reference*. A partir de aquí monto mi objeto e intento llamar a la función del WebService que recibe mi objeto y me devuelve si el envío ha sido correcto o no.

La parte del intento de conexión:

```vb
Dim store As Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store = New Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store("My")
            store.Open(Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags.ReadOnly)
            Dim CertificadoCorrecto As New System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
''Asigno el correcto temporalmente. He comprobado que esta en la posicion 1
CertificadoCorrecto = store.Certificates(1)

''Objeto que almacenara la respuesta de la funcion del Web Service
Dim resp As New ServiceReference1.RespuestaLRFEmitidasType

Dim Ws As New ServiceReference1.siiSOAPClient
''Asigno el certificado
Ws.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = CertificadoCorrecto
''Le paso la informacion a la funcion del Web Service esperando la respuesta. oSfe es un objeto de tipo SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas que recibe la funcion
resp = Ws.SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas(oSfe)
```

Entonces recibo el error:

```
El tipo de contenido text/html del mensaje de respuesta no coincide con el tipo de contenido del enlace (text/xml; charset=utf-8). 
Si usa un codificador personalizado, asegúrese de que el método IsContentTypeSupported se implemente correctamente. 
Los primeros 1024 bytes de la respuesta fueron: 

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html lang="es-ES">
    <head>
        <title>Agencia Tributaria - Se ha producido un error</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">       
    <link href="https://www.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/css/xzhtcs04.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
            function toggle()
            {
                var o=document.getElementById("AEAT_errores_tecnicos");
                o.style.display=(o.style.display=='' || o.style.display=='none')?'block':'none';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="body">   
        <div id="header">
        <div id="AEAT_header">
          <div id="topIzquierda">
            <div id="logoAEAT">
                <ul>
                    <li><a target="_self" href="https://www.agenciatributaria.gob.es"><span class="logoGobierno"></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a target="_self" href="http://www.agenciatributaria.es"><span class="logoAEAT"></span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>           
            </div>
```

Este es mi app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="ConexionXSD.My.MySettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="siiBinding">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="siiBinding1" />
                <binding name="siiBinding4">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="siiBinding5" />
                <binding name="siiBinding8">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="siiBinding9" />
                <binding name="siiBinding10">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="siiBinding11" />
                <binding name="siiBinding12">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="siiBinding13" />
                <binding name="siiBinding2">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="siiBinding3" />
                <binding name="siiBinding6">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="siiBinding7" />
                <binding name="siiBinding14">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="siiBinding15" />
                <binding name="siiBinding16">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="siiBinding17" />
                <binding name="siiBinding18">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="siiBinding19" />
                <binding name="siiBinding20">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="siiBinding21" />
                <binding name="siiBinding22">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="siiBinding23" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding"
                contract="wsFacturasEmitidas.siiSOAP" name="SuministroFactEmitidasPruebas" />
            <endpoint address="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/bi/SiiFactBIV1SOAP"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding4"
                contract="srBienesInversion.siiSOAP" name="SuministroBienesInversionPruebas" />
            <endpoint address="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactCOBV1SOAP"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding8"
                contract="srCobrosEmitidas.siiSOAP" name="SuministroCobrosEmitidasPruebas" />
            <endpoint address="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fr/SiiFactPAGV1SOAP"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding12"
                contract="srPagosRecibidas.siiSOAP" name="SuministroPagosRecibidasPruebas" />
            <endpoint address="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/pm/SiiFactCMV1SOAP"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding10"
                contract="srCobrosMetalico.siiSOAP" name="SuministroCobrosMetalicoPruebas" />
            <endpoint address="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding2"
                contract="srSuministroFactEmitidas.siiSOAP" name="SuministroFactEmitidasPruebas1" />
            <endpoint address="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fr/SiiFactFRV1SOAP"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding6"
                contract="rsSuministroFactRecibidas.siiSOAP" name="SuministroFactRecibidasPruebas" />
            <endpoint address="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/bi/SiiFactBIV1SOAP"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding14"
                contract="srSuministroBienesInversion.siiSOAP" name="SuministroBienesInversionPruebas1" />
            <endpoint address="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/oi/SiiFactOIV1SOAP"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding16"
                contract="rsSuministroOpIntracomunitarias.siiSOAP" name="SuministroOpIntracomunitariasPruebas" />
            <endpoint address="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactCOBV1SOAP"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding18"
                contract="rsSuministroCobrosEmitidas.siiSOAP" name="SuministroCobrosEmitidasPruebas1" />
            <endpoint address="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/pm/SiiFactCMV1SOAP"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding20"
                contract="rsSuministroCobrosMetalico.siiSOAP" name="SuministroCobrosMetalicoPruebas1" />
            <endpoint address="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fr/SiiFactPAGV1SOAP"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding22"
                contract="srSuministroPagosRecibidas.siiSOAP" name="SuministroPagosRecibidasPruebas1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <applicationSettings>
        <ConexionXSD.My.MySettings>
            <setting name="ConexionXSD_wsSuministroFactEmitidas_siiService"
                serializeAs="String">
                <value>xxxxxxxxxxxx</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ConexionXSD_wsSuministroFactRecibidas_siiService"
                serializeAs="String">
                <value>xxxxxxxxxxxx</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ConexionXSD_wsSuministroBienesInversion_siiService"
                serializeAs="String">
                <value>xxxxxxxxxxxx</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ConexionXSD_wsSuministroOpIntracomunitarias_siiService"
                serializeAs="String">
                <value>xxxxxxxxxxxx</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ConexionXSD_wsSuministroCobrosEmitidas_siiService"
                serializeAs="String">
                <value>xxxxxxxxxxxx</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ConexionXSD_wsSuministroCobrosMetalico_siiService"
                serializeAs="String">
                <value>xxxxxxxxxxxx</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ConexionXSD_wsSuministroPagosRecibidas_siiService"
                serializeAs="String">
                <value>xxxxxxxxxxxx</value>
            </setting>
        </ConexionXSD.My.MySettings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Dejo una versión del app.config mas limpia donde solo hago referencia a un wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="siiBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding"
          contract="srSuministroFactEmitidas.siiSOAP" name="SuministroFactEmitidasPruebas" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

En este punto busqué información y leí que posiblemente el error fuera por el certificado pero mediante el explorador si que accedo al Web Service usando dicho certificado. 
Seguí buscando y leí que posiblemente no debería haber usado Service Reference y sí Web Reference. Pero la verdad que estoy atascado. A ver si alguien me aporta algo de luz.

Comment: Sería bueno que editaras tu pregunta poniendo la configuración que tienes en archivo `web.config` esto nos dará más claridad de las cosas que se tendrían que ajustar para hacerlo funcionar

Comment: Estoy desarrollando la aplicacion con Windows Forms aplicación escritorio. Puede que este diciendo una tontería pero creo que no hay web.config. el servicio no es mio.

Comment: Lo que he averiguado hasta ahora es que por lo visto el problema es del certificado. La estructura XML que se envia por el web service tiene una parte de cabecera del presentador de la información que debe coincidir con la del certificado que se está usando. Es decir que el NIF del presentador presente en una etiqueta del XML debe coincidir con el NIF del certificado digital. Lo que pasa es que el error solo me devuelve 1024 caracteres y el código de error está en otra parte del texto devuelto que no recibo. En principio el tema del NIF está correcto pero sigo sin poder hacer el envío.

Comment: app.config? tampoco lo tienes?

Comment: He incluido el app.config de la aplicación.

Comment: El ejemplo que expones en la pregunta, ¿a qué EndPoint corresponde?

Comment: Lo que estoy probando de momento es el envio de facturas emitidas. <endpoint address="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding"
                contract="wsFacturasEmitidas.siiSOAP" name="SuministroFactEmitidasPruebas" />

Comment: Intentaría hacer debug, pero desgraciadamente no tengo el certificado, además de que estoy en otro país y las reglas de administración tributaria cambian de un país a otro, para saber exactamente la información que se envía. En este [link de SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481092/the-content-type-application-xmlcharset-utf-8-of-the-response-message-does-not) encontré un problema muy similar al tuyo, espero que te sea de utilidad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Falta esto y te funcionara:

```
    ws.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = CertificadoCorrecto
    ws.ClientCredentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = True
```

Y esto en el app.config:

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="siiBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="siiBinding">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <httpsTransport />
        </binding>
       </customBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: Sigo teniendo el mismo error. En la descripción del certificado veo los datos correctos y creo que lo asigno correctamente pero cuando hago el envío el resultado es el mismo. ¿Tu lo has conseguido? ¿Podrías pasar ejemplo de como lo has montado? ¿Has referenciado los WSDL por Service Reference o Web Reference? Por lo visto, según el apartado de preguntas frecuentes de la AEAT, la etiqueta de cabecera del envío, en el campo NIF debe contener el mismo que el del certificado que se está usando pero ni así lo consigo.

Comment: Si lo he conseguido, con el mismo código que el tuyo, añadiendo:
 ws.ClientCredentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = True

y añadiendo lo del app.config (importante)

Comment: No veo la edición de tu respuesta donde has incluido lo del app.config.

Comment: Rectifico. Si que esta la parte del app.config pero creo que deberias editar y marcar el codigo como tal.

Comment: Me ha funcionado con los cambios que indicabas. Pero me gustaría entender los cambios que has introducido a que se deben. Quiero decir que si sería posible que explicaras un poco la solución. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Siento no haber documentado mejor mi respuesta, SII me lleva a tope. Coment:
ws.ClientCredentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = True 
Si no es true no utiliza el certificado que has puesto en las credenciales

<transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
Le indicas que se identifique en el servicio mediante Certificado

<textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
Es la versión de Soap que demanda AEAT, por defecto .NET utiliza la Soap 12

<httpsTransport />
Indica que la comunicación se realiza por Https, esto no se si hace falta, ya que se indica en endpoint address

Comment: Yo también voy loco en el SII. Muchas gracias por tu solución y tus comentarios.

Comment: Estimados, muy util su consulta y respuesta, tengo una duda con el `endpoint`, de que forma se establece a que `endpoint` se hace referencia, estoy creando el webservice de **SuministroFacturasEmitidas** en el `app.Config` tengo tantos `endPoints` como wsdl tenga. No estoy pudiendo establecer el `endPoint` que tengo que usar y me sale un error que dice "No se encontro el extremo predeterminado..." Gracias!

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema que el mencionado, y aplicando la solución descrita, sigo teniendo el mismo problema, por que puede ser?